# Why monitorInterval in log4j2 is not reloading loggers

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j2

I have a webapp that I run on Tomcat 8.5. The attribute monitorInterval is set but when I add a logger in the config file and save, no log messages show up in the log file. The logger is valid and I have a feature that allows it to be turned on programmatically, which works. But sometimes support needs to add more specific loggers in the file without restarting Tomcat.

I'm not sure if I'm missing some configuration or something else is conflicting with reloading mechanism.

We also use Spring Framework 5.2.5

Log4J2 Configuration:

If I uncomment 'com.company.app.service' logger and save after tomcat has started, I do not see logs for classes within that package hierarchy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="FILEOUT" fileName="C:/logs/app.log" filePattern="C:/logs/app-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %-5p %C.%-5M - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers> 
    <!--Logger name="com.company.app.service" level="debug" additivity="true">
      <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT" level="debug" />
    </Logger-->
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="FILEOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here are some dependencies we use:

```
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.3'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.13.3'
compile 'org.dblock.log4jna:log4jna-api:2.0'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.13.3'
```

Log4J2 Console output when setting Configuration status to debug:

```
2020-08-07 17:31:50,667 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Apache Log4j Core 2.13.3 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml]
2020-08-07 17:31:50,699 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Installed 3 script engines
2020-08-07 17:31:50,771 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Groovy Scripting Engine version: 2.0, language: Groovy, threading: MULTITHREADED, compile: true, names: [groovy, Groovy], factory class: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineFactory
2020-08-07 17:31:50,804 localhost-startStop-1 INFO Cannot initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ContextFactory
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader._jr$defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:42016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2395)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:857)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1182)
        at net.jawr.web.util.js.rhino.RhinoScriptEngine.<clinit>(RhinoScriptEngine.java:91)
        at net.jawr.web.util.js.rhino.RhinoScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(RhinoScriptEngineFactory.java:76)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.<init>(ScriptManager.java:100)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:618)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:691)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:708)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:138)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:30)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1182)
        ... 47 more
2020-08-07 17:31:50,818 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 124 plugins
2020-08-07 17:31:50,819 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2020-08-07 17:31:50,853 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
2020-08-07 17:31:50,881 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2020-08-07 17:31:50,969 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2020-08-07 17:31:51,034 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p %C.%-5M - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2020-08-07 17:31:51,037 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 46 plugins
2020-08-07 17:31:51,147 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,200 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG createPolicy(size="10 MB")
2020-08-07 17:31:51,209 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,211 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG createPolicy(={SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)})
2020-08-07 17:31:51,220 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,268 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="C:/logs/app.log", filePattern="C:/logs/app-%i.log", append="null", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)])), Strategy=null, advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p %C.%-5M - %m%n), name="FILEOUT", Configuration(file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4JConfig.xml), Filter=null, ={})
2020-08-07 17:31:51,306 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Returning file creation time for C:\logs\app.log
2020-08-07 17:31:51,307 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager C:/logs/app.log
2020-08-07 17:31:51,314 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2020-08-07 17:31:51,340 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Setting prev file time to 2020-08-07T16:20:29.565-0700
2020-08-07 17:31:51,341 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Initializing triggering policy CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)])
2020-08-07 17:31:51,342 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Initializing triggering policy SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)
2020-08-07 17:31:51,343 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,344 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p %C.%-5M - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2020-08-07 17:31:51,347 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,349 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG createPolicy(size="10 MB")
2020-08-07 17:31:51,354 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,355 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG createPolicy(={SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)})
2020-08-07 17:31:51,356 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,358 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="C:/logs/trace.log", filePattern="C:/logs/trace-%i.log", append="null", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)])), Strategy=null, advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p %C.%-5M - %m%n), name="TRACE", Configuration(file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4JConfig.xml), Filter=null, ={})
2020-08-07 17:31:51,449 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2020-08-07 17:31:51,454 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG createLoggers(={root})
2020-08-07 17:31:51,455 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml] initialized
2020-08-07 17:31:51,456 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml]
2020-08-07 17:31:51,466 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Log4j2 ConfigurationScheduler starting 1 threads
2020-08-07 17:31:51,472 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml] OK.
2020-08-07 17:31:51,473 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2020-08-07 17:31:51,474 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG OutputStream closed
2020-08-07 17:31:51,475 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2020-08-07 17:31:51,476 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
2020-08-07 17:31:51,482 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@5b49d26f OK
2020-08-07 17:31:51,500 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b
2020-08-07 17:31:51,514 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=StatusLogger
2020-08-07 17:31:51,522 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=ContextSelector
2020-08-07 17:31:51,531 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=Loggers,name=
2020-08-07 17:31:51,540 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=Appenders,name=TRACE
2020-08-07 17:31:51,541 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=Appenders,name=SECURITY
2020-08-07 17:31:51,542 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=Appenders,name=SPRINGFRAMEWORK
2020-08-07 17:31:51,543 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=4fc55a6b,component=Appenders,name=FILEOUT
2020-08-07 17:31:51,561 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
2020-08-07 17:31:51,566 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=4fc55a6b] at URI file:C:/opt/app/conf/log4jConfig.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@180f6ae1) with optional ClassLoader: null
2020-08-07 17:31:51,568 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2020-08-07 17:31:51,572 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG LoggerContext[name=4fc55a6b, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@180f6ae1] started OK.
2020-08-07 17:31:53,653 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
2020-08-07 17:31:53,661 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
```

Comment: If you add status="debug" to the Configuration element you should see it reconfigure when it sees that the file is updated. Do you?

Comment: No I don't. If I set status to trace, then I see entries such as 'Log4j2-TF-5-Scheduled-1 TRACE WatchRunnable' in the tomcat console. But with debug I don't see those (besides the initial startup messages log4j2 prints).

Comment: Can you add that output to your question?

Comment: I Added the console output.

Comment: I'm also using JDK 11.

Comment: Yes, I can tell that because scripting is disabled by default. Everything you've showed looks normal except the configuration isn't detecting that the file was modified. I have no idea why File.lastModified would not have a new value if the file had changed. I do find this rather odd because we have unit tests to verify reconfiguration that we regularly run on windows.